# VS Code unable to rename folder on Windows 10. I get "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename..."

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, windows-10

## Problem:

VS Code is unable to rename folders in JavaScript projects when this folder contains a file with an 'import' statement that imports a file from a subfolder.

Since this is a very common situation in js projects, this has become a very frequent problem.

When the issue manifests itself, I get the error:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'd:\project\parentFolder' -> 'd:\project\newName'
```

## How to Make the Issue Manifest Itself:

**The Setup:**

Inside an empty project,

- Create a folder (parentFolder)
- Create a .js file inside the folder (parentFile.js)
- Create a subfolder inside the folder (childFolder)
- Create a .js file inside the subfolder (childFile.js)
- Import the child file from the parent file using JavaScript import statement

[image]

**Getting the Issue**

- Open the parentFile.js in VS Code
- Try to rename the parent folder

VS Code will hang, the bottom bar will say it's trying to rename the file, and after a while, the file won't be renamed and I get the error stated above.

If VS Code is reloaded and the parentFile.js is kept closed, the issue won't appear. But if it was opened once, even if the file is closed before renaming it, the issue will appear.

## Relevant Info:

- Windows 10 (Dell Precision M6700)
- VS Code version 1.74.2 x64 (I tried both 'user' and 'system' install options)
- I tested removing all extensions and settings from VS Code
- I tested removing node.js from my machine
- I formatted my machine recently. I was having this issue before and I continue to have it after

## Edit:

- I formatted my PC again, installed VS Code right away (and no other program) but the problem persists.
- I tried it on a different PC (win 10, Dell), and had the same issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem - works fine for me following your steps.

Comment: @topsail, this might be a tricky one. VS Code bugging with only a simple import statement is (to me) an indication that the problem might be in my machine...

Comment: I am having the same issue. It's happening on a new laptop with Windows 11 pro. It wasn't happening on my older laptop with Windows 10 pro. @LucasChammaNahas has this been resolved?

Comment: @ghd, no I haven't found a solution to this problem

Comment: Open Vscode as admin - The solution worked for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707277/vs-code-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: run vscode as administrator?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found out that the solution is to stop the development server before renaming the folders.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem. What worked for me is changing the name in the file explorer rather than vscode. Give it a go!

Comment: Only an option which helped me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've found that in my case the problem is caused, because VS code marks the open project (folder) as being used, and hence cannot by modified by other programs or processes. But for some reason the VS code renaming process is being stopped by this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Close all tab of project in VS Code (or another IDE same). Then you can rename this.
Hope this help you.

[image: Close all - Context Menu]

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was the extension called "Live Server" by "Ritwick Dey". Disabling that fixed the issue for me. I hope it helps

Comment: After doing this happens sometimes. but turning off the node server fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove .vscode(it's a hidden folder so show hidden items first) folder if exists if this didn't help
check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58707277)

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting .vscode does not work... I even tried a completely fresh installation of VS Code, with no luck...

Regarding the question you sent, they don't seem to have solved it either... Although the issue seems to be exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and in my case, it was caused by a VSCode extension, specifically the Live Server extension. Disabling this extension resolved the problem for me. If you don't have Live Server installed, consider checking other VSCode extensions. Additionally, make sure to stop any local servers.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to stop the server and then you rename the folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, close all tabs and close all terminal does the job. Just make sure no activity is running or tab opened.

Answer (score 0):

best way is using other code editors

like :
press `ctrl + shift + p` and type `reload window`

then rename it

Answer (score 0):

Disable the wsl extension if you are on windows.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got fixed but updating my vscode going to help -> install update, then restarting the IDE after the update finished.